# Essbase Report Script - Issues with Calculated Column

Tags: essbase

I have written an Essbase Report Script to retrieve data from Essbase. The report script also contains a calculated column.

The output of this Essbase Report Script only displays the calculated column's header and does not display any values in the column. I have used ONCOLCALCS command in the report script and have used an ORDER command as well.

Could you please suggest what might be wrong with the report script or if a change needs to be made to any of the Essbase settings in order for the report script to display data in the calculated column?

Comment: What is the formula for the calculated column? Have you verified that it's actually able to generate data for that intersection?

Comment: Hi jwj, It's a calculated column that I want to introduce in the output of the report script besides the data that is already available in the Essbase cube. Also, is it possible to calculate values for this column based on conditions satisfied by values in other columns. For eg. If (3rd Column value - 2nd Column value) > 0 then (3rd column value - 2nd column value)*0.1 ELSE 0. Can something of this sort be accomplished through Essbase report script?

Comment: In my experience I have mostly tried to stay away from doing calculations in a report script at all. The functionality that they provide there is very, very rudimentary. I think you are much better off creating a new member or new dynamic calc member that will do the calculation for you, then use *that* as you would any other member. You'd be able to quite easily handle the case that you mention.